# Sharepoint 2013 workflow not available in Platform type Sharepoint 2013 designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

I have configured and installed and registered the workflow successfully. (I think i did). I can confirm in the Central Administration and check the status of workflow service application proxy is said "Workflow connected".

I also have installed workflow client in all the server in the farm.

So, When I try to create a workflow using SharePoint 2013 designer, the message

> The option for the sharepoint 2013 workflow platform is not available because the workflow service is not configured on the server. Please contact your server administrator

Any suggesstion?